# Symfony2 translation issue

Tags: symfony, translation

## Initial situation

I fetch the current weekday in my Controller

```
$dayname = date('l');
```

For translation I have one dedicated translation file only for the weekdays (`weekdays.de.yml`)

```
Monday:  Montag
Tuesday: Dienstag
# ...
```

Now I pass the PHP variable `$dayname` to my twig file, so that I could call it there with using the `trans` filter.

```
{% trans_default_domain 'weekdays' %}
{{ dayname|trans }}
```

Easy going, works fine.

## Objective target

To keep my `translations` folder tidied up, I want to migrate those `weekdays.de.yml` into one large single translation file, where I not just organize the weekdays, but all translation elements, e.g. `trans.en.yml`, `trans.de.yml` and `trans.fr.yml`.

```
# trans.en.yml
# ...
weekdays:
    monday:  Monday
    tuesday: Tuesday
    # ...

# trans.de.yml
# ...
weekdays:
    monday:  Montag
    tuesday: Dienstag
    # ...
```

I now could call the appropriate weekday in my twig file like this, e.g. for Monday:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'trans' %}
{{ weekdays.monday|trans }}
```

But how can I pass the `$dayname` variable to the twig file and chose the weekday from my according translation file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ ('weekdays.'~ dayname )|trans }}` should do it

Comment: It's `weekdays` (with trailing `s`). But this works fine. Thanks!